# Android Relativelayout click background behaviour

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin

So i have a `RecyclerView` and it is populated by my custom layout (code below). I have made a background drawable and set it on the root of my custom layout so that when user clicks the item, the background colour changes. There is also an options button (3 dots) on every item's layout, which is also clickable and also needs to change the background colour when clicked.

The problem is, when i set my drawable as background for the options menu the whole layout doesn't change colour when clicked (screens below)

When i set the background on options menu as `"?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`, everything works fine.

Code for my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_click"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:text="Caption"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_menu"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ellipsis_v"
        android:background="@drawable/item_click" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for the drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/primary_100" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/primary_100" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

Item selected when the background of the options menu is set to `"?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` (I want the whole row to change colour to blue):
[image: Screenshot1]

Item selected when the background of the options menu is set to my drawable:
[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the default state of your selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/primary_100" />
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/primary_100" />
<item
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: But i want to change the clicked background color. selectableItemBackground has the default color

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Your image background is white, so it will cover the background of its container. Create a selector where the default state is transparent, not white then. See my edited answer.

Comment: Do you mean like the image file (the png) background is white?

Comment: Not the image itself, the selector. See my updated answer to fix the issue.